How to add pattern to one category in ggplot
I have a data below:
data <- structure(list(individual = c("47%", "41%", "12%", "5%", NA, 
"39%", "29%", "12%", "5%", NA, "44%", "39%", "28%", "31%", NA, 
"60%", "59%", "26%", "36%", NA, "73%", "48%", "52%", "36%", NA, 
"49%", "43%", "NA%", "3%", NA, "32%", "34%", "NA%", "2%", NA), 
    group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("SNs", 
    "SMNs", "NMSC", "Breast cancer", "Thyroid cancer", "Meningioma", 
    "Sarcoma"), class = "factor"), group2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, NA), levels = c("CCSS-All treatments", "CCSS-PRS", 
    "SJLIFE-All treatments", "SJLIFE-PRS"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(47, 41, 12, 5, NA, 39, 29, 12, 5, NA, 44, 39, 28, 
    31, NA, 60, 59, 26, 36, NA, 73, 48, 52, 36, NA, 49, 43, NA, 
    3, NA, 32, 34, NA, 2, NA), id = 1:35, group3 = c("SJLIFE", 
    "CCSS", "SJLIFE", "CCSS", NA, "SJLIFE", "CCSS", "SJLIFE", 
    "CCSS", NA, "SJLIFE", "CCSS", "SJLIFE", "CCSS", NA, "SJLIFE", 
    "CCSS", "SJLIFE", "CCSS", NA, "SJLIFE", "CCSS", "SJLIFE", 
    "CCSS", NA, "SJLIFE", "CCSS", "SJLIFE", "CCSS", NA, "SJLIFE", 
    "CCSS", "SJLIFE", "CCSS", NA), group4 = c("All treatments", 
    "All treatments", "PRS", "PRS", NA, "All treatments", "All treatments", 
    "PRS", "PRS", NA, "All treatments", "All treatments", "PRS", 
    "PRS", NA, "All treatments", "All treatments", "PRS", "PRS", 
    NA, "All treatments", "All treatments", "PRS", "PRS", NA, 
    "All treatments", "All treatments", "PRS", "PRS", NA, "All treatments", 
    "All treatments", "PRS", "PRS", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -35L
), class = "data.frame")

I want to plot the barplot and add stripe to "CCSS" category in group3 and color in group4, so I want two legends. How do I do that?
This is my current code:
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group4)) +      
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group4), stat="identity", alpha=1, width=0.95) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern=group3), 
    fill = 'white',
    colour = 'black', 
    pattern_density = 0.5
  ) 


This will achieve your desired output. You may need to tweak some of the parameters to get it exactly how you want. I have included a non-exhaustive number of options for adjusting the patterns to help you on your way.
I have filtered the "CCSS" values using dplyr::filter(). Given the NA values do not show in the plot, I omitted them from the legend using scale_fill_discrete(na.translate = FALSE), remove this line if it does not suit.
library(dplyr) # 1.1.4 
library(ggplot2) # 3.5.1
library(ggpattern) # 1.0.1

ggplot() +      
  geom_bar(data = data,
           aes(x = as.factor(id), y = value, fill = group4), 
           stat = "identity", 
           alpha = 1, 
           width = 0.95) +
  geom_bar_pattern(data = filter(data, group3 == "CCSS"),
                   aes(x = as.factor(id), y = value, pattern = group3),
                   stat = "identity",
                   fill = NA,
                   width = 1,
                   colour = 'black',
                   pattern_density = 0.1,
                   pattern_spacing = .03,
                   pattern_fill = NA,
                   pattern_colour = "black",
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6,
                   inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = "stripe") +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)

# Warning messages:
# 1: Removed 9 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
# (`geom_bar()`). 


